# Would you recommend IPtables/Netfilter as a main firewall for an ISP?

Tags: firewall, network-core, isp

As the title says. And since we are doing our own Support. Would it be recommended? I am talking about the Main firewall of the ISP, the Firewall that routes your data to the Router before exiting to the internet.

Of course everyone has their own opinions but I would like to have an answer based from experience or from advanced theoretical knowledge.

Comment: What kind of ISP are we talking about here?

Comment: A new ISP, with around 3000 clients, gives internet service only through Wifi and FTTH.

Comment: I have 4 ibgp peers and 2 uplinks going to two different ISP's...

Comment: As it is, this question will only lead to opinion based answers.

Comment: I rephrased question, I am looking for some professional advice as I will need to implement this. If there is something missing kindly add it as this is a very important question.Thanks.

Comment: Frankly, it is not any better. Anything staring with "Would you recommend" leads to opinion based answer. This question could be asked in [chat].